# Display images in Preview at full resolution on a Mac with Retina display?

Tags: resolution, preview, retina

If I download an image from the web that has say 720x720 pixels at 72dpi, when I open this in Preview, it displays an image that is 10"X 10" at 72dpi. But... the Retina display on my MBP has a native resolution o 220dpi!

How can I get Preview to size the image down so that it displays at the full 220dpi resolution?

Thanks!

Comment: I posted some tricks on that question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174794/retina-display-how-to-display-images-in-native-pixel-resolution-in-finder-and-p/41174795#41174795